# Increase turtle speed gradually in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm new in NetLogo. 
I have a set of turtles and some predators. 
When the turtles see one or more predators in their vision-radius, they move quickyly away. 
What I want to change is the speed of the turtles, I'd like they change their speed gradually at each tick. 
I tried to use this code but it doesn't work. Acceleration is a slider that goes from 0.0001 to 0.0099.

```
to avoid
  turn-away (towards nearest-predator) max-avoid-turn
  set speed speed + acceleration
  fd speed
end
```

How can I do?
Thank you!!

Comment: This code appears correct to me. What's your evidence that it doesn't work? I think the problem must be in code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: If it doesn't look like the speed is changing, it could just be that the acceleration values are too low. That is, the speed *is* changing, just too small to be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Set your acceleration slider from 0 to 1 and put it at 1. If you don't see anything noticeable after that, you'll have to lend us more context. However, I think that should do the trick.